# How to write wildcards for any character in groovy

Tags: regex, groovy, soapui

I want to know how in groovy scripting can I apply a wildcard character? For example in instead of having a long list like:

```
def name1 = 'name1'
def name2 = 'name2'
def name3 = 'name3'
```

I would be happy if the string could be any of those names, so I am not bothered if it's 1,2 or 3, as long as it has a characters after 'name' then it's ok. That means I can have one variable like:

```
def name = 'name' + wildcard
```

A little bit like sql where you just want anything beginning where if you want to searrch for something like name..., you would write LIKE 'name%'.

Thanks

Update:

I have three variables:

```
def ns4 = 'ns4:testResponse'
def ns3 = 'ns3:testResponse'
def ns2 = 'ns2:testResponse'
```

But instead I want to set a variable for any ns test tag tag so I tried this:

```
def ns = 'ns' +/[\d]+/':testResponse'
```

But I get an Script36.groovy: 17: expecting EOF, found ':testResponse'

I also tried `def ns = 'ns' +/[\d]+/+':testResponse'`but when I perform an assert between ns2 and ns I get this:

```
assert ns2 == ns | | | | | ns[\d]+:testResponse | false ns2:testResponse
```

virtually I don't want to provide multiple if statements like so:

```
if (response.contains(ns2)...
else if (response.contains(ns3)..
else if (response.contains(ns4) etc
```

I am actually not bothered about the number within either:

```
def ns4 = 'ns4:testResponse'
def ns3 = 'ns3:testResponse'
def ns2 = 'ns2:testResponse'
```

So I wanted to implement a wildcard instead of a number so then i can have only one def variable and one if statement rather than 3 def variables and 3 if statements.

So I want to change this:

```
    def ns4 = 'ns4:testResponse'
    def ns3 = 'ns3:testResponse'
    def ns2 = 'ns2:testResponse'

...

    if (response.contains(ns2)...
    else if (response.contains(ns3)..
    else if (response.contains(ns4) etc
```

into something like this:

```
def ns = 'ns' +/[\d]+/':testResponse'

...

if (response.contains(ns)
```

Sample Response:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns5:testResponse>
      </ns5:testResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

So in the response above, you can see I have a tag that states: `<ns5:testResponse`

However dependent on the request, the number within this tag can change, it could either:

```
<ns3:testResponse
<ns4:testResponse
<ns5:testResponse
<ns6:testResponse
<ns7:testResponse
```

Now instead of having if statements for if response contains either: `<ns3:testResponse` or `<ns4:testResponse` or this `<ns5:testResponse` or etc,

I just want to make sure it contains the tag `<ns*:testResponse` where star is any number so it can match any of the 5 tags mentioned above

Comment: It would be much simpler if you can attach the sample response and what you are trying to assert than all the above which is not useful at all.

Comment: @Rao I provided the sample response and what I am trying to do, hopefully it makes more sense now?

Comment: Are you trying XPath match? Or comparing xml?  Or something else? Please clarify.

Comment: Just comparing xml via a script assertion

Comment: It is difficult to image and extract the use case while it can be simple if that is part of the question.  Would you mind putting both xml which are comparing?

Comment: By the way, can check this comparison of xmls? - https://github.com/nmrao/soapUIGroovyScripts/tree/master/groovy/compare

Comment: I think I am complicated what I am wanting. All I want a variable like def ns = '<ns' +/[\d]+/+':availabilityResponse> and want to use it to compare to any of these output: '<ns4:availabilityResponse>' OR
OR '<ns3:availabilityResponse>' OR '<ns2:availabilityResponse>' . That's all I want but the assertion fails

Comment: When I tried your answer below, it didn't work for me in my actual example so I am wondering if I am implementing this incorrectly: def ns = '<ns' +/[\d]+/+':availabilityResponse>'.

Comment: Oh wait I didn't see this... ==~ I thought it was ==

Comment: That might be why it fails

Comment: That was the reason, sorry about that Rao and thank you very much like always on your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to identify number in regular expression, use `\d`. If you are expecting more than one digit, then use `\d+`.

Here is the sample script:

```
def list = ['name1','name2', 'name10a']
def pattern = /name[\d]+/
list.collect { assert it ==~ pattern }
```

If you looks the list, the last element is not in the same pattern as it has *character* after two digits.

Output:

```
groovy> def list = ['name1','name2', 'name10a'] 
groovy> def pattern = /name[\d]+/ 
groovy> list.collect { assert it ==~ pattern } 

Exception thrown

Assertion failed: 

assert it ==~ pattern
       |  |   |
       |  |   name[\d]+
       |  false
       name10a

    at ConsoleScript5$_run_closure1.doCall(ConsoleScript5:3)
    at ConsoleScript5.run(ConsoleScript5:3)
```

Comment: Ok cool so one last thing, if I want to put this in a def to state maybe I want to display tag which is '<name*:available>' where star is actually any character. Is it written as:   groovy> def name = <name/name[\d]+/:available>  ?

Comment: @BruceyBandit, would appreciate if you specify your use clearly along with sample response and what to verify.

Comment: I have included un update above on what I am trying to do and the error I received

Comment: I also tried: def ns = 'ns' +/[\d]+/+':availabilityResponse' but this gave me an output of ns[\d]+:availabilityResponse

Comment: Sorry, that did not help. Can I reiterate to provide info asked in the previous comment?

Comment: i updated my update in the question, hopefully that provides you clearer info on what I am trying to do